# AWS Amplify - Error when trying to run amplify mock

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to use the local debugging features of the AWS Amplify CLI. I have an api setup that deploys and works fine in AWS, but when I try to run:

```
amplify mock
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to start API Mock endpoint Error: Could not process value node undefined
```

Is there any way to get more detailed error information to debug this error?